# how to pass arguments to a module in python 2.x interactive mode

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

I'm using Python 2.7, and I have the following simple script, which expects one command line argument:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

if (len(sys.argv) == 2):
   print "Thanks for passing ", sys.argv[1]
else:
   print "Oops."
```

I can do something like this from the command line:

```
My-Box:~/$ ./useArg.py asdfkjlasdjfdsa
    Thanks for passing  asdfkjlasdjfdsa
```

or this:

```
My-Box:~/$ ./useArg.py 
    Oops.
```

I would like to do something similar from the interactive editor:

```
>>> import useArg asdfasdf
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    import useArg asdfasdf
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

but I don't know how. How can I pass a parameters to import/reload in the interactive editor ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't. Wrap your code inside the function

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

def main(args):
    if (len(args) == 2):
        print "Thanks for passing ", args[1]
    else:
        print "Oops."

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```

If you execute your script from command line you can do it like before, if you want to use it from interpreter:

```
import useArg
useArg.main(['foo', 'bar'])
```

In this case you have to use some dummy value at the first position of the list, so most of the time much better solution is to use [argparse library](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html). You can also check the number of command line arguments before calling the main function:

```
import sys

def main(arg):
    print(arg)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) == 2:
        main(sys.argv[1])
    else:
        main('Oops')
```

You can find good explanation what is going on when you execute `if __name__ == '__main__':` here:  [What does if __name__ == "__main__": do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)

Comment: You should also add an example of how to call the script interactively to make your answer complete.